# Why does ftell skips some positions in the file?

Tags: c, file, fopen, fgetc, ftell

I have a text file named myfile.txt which reads:

```
line 1
l
```

My code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    FILE *f = fopen("myfile.txt","r");
    if(f==NULL){
        FILE *fp=fopen("myfile.txt","w");
        fclose(fp);
        f = fopen("myfile.txt","r");
    }
    while(!feof(f)){
        printf("\ncharacter number %d    ",ftell(f));
        putchar(fgetc(f));      
    }
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is :

```
character number 0    l
character number 1    i
character number 2    n
character number 3    e
character number 4
character number 5    1
character number 6

character number 8    l
character number 9
```

Whenever a \n is encountered, the ftell skips one value for example it has skipped the value 7. Why is it so? Please explain me in detail, I want to know.

Comment: Please see related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10651108/why-does-ftell-shows-wrong-position-after-fread?rq=1

Comment: Are you using Windows by any chance?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya yes I am using windows.

Comment: @ChaitanyaVaishampayan Its giving correct output in gcc 5.4.0

Comment: @Rajeshkumar Read the question again. The question is not about correct or wrong output but it is about why is the number 7 getting skipped.

Comment: Try it with "rb" for the mode.

Comment: Should have used `printf("%d", fgetc(f));` instead of `putchar(fgetc(f));` to garner more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the newline character, which in Windows is `\r\n` ([Does Windows carriage return \r\n consist of two characters or one character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013034/does-windows-carriage-return-r-n-consist-of-two-characters-or-one-character)).

Try changing these:

```
fopen("myfile.txt","r");
```

to these:

```
fopen("myfile.txt","rb");
```

where `b` is for binary mode.

Binary mode makes a difference on Windows where text mode maps the two character carriage return, line feed sequence to a single new-line character. Note: No mapping is needed on Linux.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked with "rb". Can you please explain how does /r/n affects my program?

Comment: @ChaitanyaVaishampayan updated. Hope that helps!

Comment: @axiac i mistakenly typed /r/n. I meant \r\n.